# Adding dynamic links to multiple background images...

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image

Check out the <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/uXA4N/2/)</kbd> here.

As you can see, I have two small background images in the same `<div>`.

I'd like to be able to link each one to the appropriate link on the web. Not quite sure how to do this one...

**CSS for this div...**

```
.iso-container li   {
    background: #f8981d;
    background-image: url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/pdf-button.png), url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/bxw_email.png);
    background-position: 75% 90%, 25% 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

Comment: when you say link them to the appropriate link, do you mean like an anchor tag? have you looked into <a href ..> ?  are you looking to make links when the pointer is hovering over the images?

Comment: Yes. I can create href tags for a single background image, but multiple background images, I've never done that before.

Comment: That's because it's impossible. There is no point in it, just make them into two elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do something like this:

```
 <style>
.iso-container li   {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f8981d;
    font-size: 0.01em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .9em;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1.2em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1.2em;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1.2em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1.2em;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 1.2em;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1.2em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1.2em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1.2em;
    border-top-right-radius: 1.2em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1.2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.2em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}

.iso-container li a{
    width: 20px;
    padding: 10px;

}

</style>

<ul class="iso-container clearfix">
  <li class="item" id="_1">
    <h3 class="doc title">2013-2014 Verification Worksheet <br />(Dependent)</h3>
    <a href="your link">
        <img src="http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/pdf-button.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="your link">
        <img src="http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/bxw_email.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```